# Converting Distance to miles in Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, distance

Im working on a simple "as the crow flies" distance calculator in Google Maps and im stuck trying to convert the returned distance between two points into miles. Is there an easy way to this?

I am fairly new at this and appreciate any and all help.

Here is where i am at currently:

http://www.public.asu.edu/~tpeiffer/

Answer (score 15):

It appears that the `computeDistanceBetween` function returns distances in meters – to convert to miles, just multiply by the number of miles in a meter:

```
result *= 0.000621371192;
```

Comment: Lol! We were both answering at the same time and gave the same answer. Mine is fractionally more accurate as 1 mile is exactly 1609.344 metres, but we were both right really.

Comment: Oh, fine. The reciprocal of my number is 1609.3440006, which _is_ essentially the same.

Comment: As I say, we were both right. And you got the upvote. And an upvote from me too!

Answer (score 3):

I am going to guess that the distance is given in metres, in which case you simply divide it by 1609.344.

My guess is a bit Rainman... I picked two points which are an 80 mile drive apart and the answer was around 90000. Since 90km is around 54-55 miles (sums done roughly in head) and it's not a straight line in the car, this seems reasonable to me!

Comment: I should add that dividing by 1609.344 gives exactly the right answer. i didn't guess at that bit. i'm the sort of nerd who just knows stuff like that... ;-)